# Plotly Dash - Adding Horizontal Line on Bar Plot

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a horizontal line on my bar chart, which I was able to do like so using a scatterplot as another trace.[image]

However, because the red line does not extend fully, I'm trying to use the Shapes parameter in go.Layout but it is giving me this error:

> Invalid value of type 'builtins.dict' received for the 'shapes' property of layout
> Received value: {'type': 'line', 'x0': 0, 'y0': 2, 'x1': 4, 'y1': 2, 'line': {'color': 'red', 'width': 4, 'dash': 'dashdot'}}
> The 'shapes' property is a tuple of instances of
> Shape that may be specified as:
> - A list or tuple of instances of plotly.graph_objs.layout.Shape
> - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties that
> will be passed to the Shape constructor

This is the code

```
bar_chart = [go.Bar(x=competitor_df.index,
                    y=competitor_df['competitor_cost'],
                    marker_color=colors,
                    marker_line_width=1.5,
                    marker_line_color='#505461',
                    textposition='outside',
                    texttemplate="$%{y}")]
                 
layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(range=[0, competitor_df.max]),
                   xaxis=dict(range=[0, 4]),
                   shapes=dict(
                               type='line', 
                               x0=0, 
                               y0=2, 
                               x1=4, 
                               y1=2, 
                               line=dict(color='red', width=4, dash='dashdot')))
    
fig = {'data':bar_chart, 'layout':layout}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in plotly with categorical data. You will need to use absolute/paper positioning for your horizontal line, something like

```
fig.add_shape(type="line",
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x0=0, y0=0.8,
    x1=1, y1=0.8,
    line=dict(
        color="magenta",
        width=3,
    ),
             )
```